# Как simple_html_dom искать в найденом

Tags: simple-html-dom, html, синтаксический-анализ

Не могу сообразить как simple_html_dom искать в найденом

```
$dom = str_get_html($html);
foreach($dom->find('div[class=reportsLine status_SUCCESS]') as $line) {
        $date[] = $line->find('span[class=date]')->plaintext;
    }
```

Не хочет работать (

```
<div class="reportsLine status_SUCCESS" data-container-name="item">
<i class="icon icon_SUCCESS fa fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="icon icon_ERROR fa fa-times-circle"></i>
<i class="icon icon_PROCESSED fa fa-clock-o"></i>

<div class="DateWithTransaction">
    <span class="date">10.08.2014</span>
    <span class="time">12:44:08</span>

        <div class="transaction">999999900352603390</div>

</div>

    <div class="IncomeWithExpend income">
        <div class="cash">3,00 руб. </div>
        <div class="commission">

        </div>

    </div>

<div class="originalExpense">
    <span>3,00 руб. </span>
</div>

<div class="ProvWithComment">
    <div class="provider">
        <span>Visa QIWI Wallet</span>
        <span class="opNumber">+79835872519</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">test2</div>
</div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<div class="extra" data-container-name="item-extra">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="key">Транзакция:</span>
        <span class="value">999999900352603390</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

</div>

Comment: Выглядит правильно. Что находится в $dom?

Comment: в дом находится html страницы

Comment: $date[]

выдает следующее


Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: Да пропустил строчку с дом случайно когда смотрел :) Ну значит при парсинге нашлось 3 элемента у которых не нашлись спаны. Еще бы html выложили бы.

Comment: часть html выложил в вопросе

Comment: @wapik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
$dom = str_get_html($html);

$reportsLines = $dom->find('div[class=reportsLine status_SUCCESS]');
//$reportsLines = $dom->find('div[class=reportsLine status_SUCCESS]',0);Может быть так надо написать. В общем смысл что мы берем первый из найденых элементов
foreach($reportsLines->find('span[class=date]') as $line) {
        $date[] = $line->plaintext;
    }
```

В цикле foreach перебирается массив найденных элементов по выражению "span[class=date]".